# What does this error means? 'Oracle.ManagedDataAcess.Client'

Tags: c#, vb.net, oracle, winforms, visual-studio

I just get project from my friend for learning some stuff, the project is simple windows forms application made in Visual Studio (VB as code behind), he moved the project to my machine and we run the project without any problems, it connected to the database and we get results from DB loaded into grid.

But when I tried to edit some stuff on the project like adding new DATASET I received this error, and even when I want to add new QUERY in TABLE ADAPTER or if I want to see the code of existing dataset I am receiving again the same error.

[image]

This means I am missing some DLL's in my visual studio?

Comment: It seems to suggest that you don't have the Oracle data provider installed.  You should go to the Oracle web site and download the data tools for .NET.

Comment: I was always confused from the terminology used there, so I try to explain this how I see it: When You create program, You need to connect to some other database. As a negotiator between **App** and **Database** You must use some DataAccess provider. There are multiple version for multiple Databases (e.g. for MySQL, MS-SQL, Oracle DB, Postrgee....) and as Databases syntax changes, there are multiple versions. The best You can do check what version is used by Your colleague and download the same from the Oracle web - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

Comment: @Tatranskymedved well my friend thanks a lot I'm installing some stuffs from Oracle's site so we will see what's gonna happen

Comment: Have it helped?

Comment: @Tatranskymedved acctually Yes, I installed ODT for VS2013 and problem is solved! :)

Answer (score 0):

When You create the application and it should connect to some database system, it needs to have a negotiator between the **App** and the **Database**. For this purpose You must use some `DataAccess provider`.

There exist multiple versions for all the Databases (MySQL, MS-SQL, Oracle DB, Postgree...). As the DB syntax is evolving (the language), also the versions of `DataAccess providers` are increasing.

Basically each DB requires some minimal version of provider to work with. As Your computer does not have any valid installed, it throws errors. The best You can do check what version is used by Your colleague and download the same or higher from [the Oracle web](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html)).